# Azure Devops path for Power Platform CD

Tags: azure, azure-devops, power-platform

I'm Trying to setup a Release CD for D365 (or Power Platform) using the "Power Platform Deploy Package" task:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/alm/devops-build-tool-tasks

I can see the build and release are flowing correct except for the very last part.

I can tell it works all the way to the "Download Artifact" part "
[Download Artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pIqmb.png)

Do I need anything else beside those 2?:

[pipeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04HqU.png)

I get this "Package File not specified or not found" error:

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0l7y.png)

same error with several combinations of env variable paths. tried the exact path and still does not work

Am I forgetting anything?

[path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7NnUI.png)

The code is produced with the VS CRM Package and compiled just fine. I only updated the .net  framework version to 4.7.2.

[vs template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyiPO.png)

Comment: Hi, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Hosted agent instead of Self-hosted agent, we need to specify the path  using [predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#build-variables-devops-services) `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` instead of `D:\a\r1\a`, then it should be work.

Also we could add the task [Copy files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to filter the `.dll` file and copy them to another path, then specify the Package File path.

Note: I just share the yaml sample, you could enter the variable to class edit mode(UI)

```
- task: CopyFiles@2
  displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    Contents: |
      $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/_Demo-CI/drop/bin/Debug/*.dll
    TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
```